Suppress X-POWERED-BY header in .Net Core web site without using web.config
I look after a collection of a few dozen similar web sites, hosted on an Azure Web App service running under Windows and IIS. To keep things manageable and cut out duplication, their Startup and Program classes all derive from one single common Startup and Program class. And there are no web.config files.
It sends a X-POWERED-BY header in every response. I want to suppress this.
I've seen how to suppress this using web.config, but I much prefer not to do this, so I don't have to give every site a web.config.
In the program.cs, I set AddServerHeader to false, but the X-Powered-By header is still sent.
.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false) // doesn't work

In the startup.cs class, I tried to remove the header in the Configure method, to no avail:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
        await next();
    });   // doesn't work

In the startup.cs class, I also tried to set the header to empty string in the Configure method, again to no avail:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers["X-Powered-By"] = "";
        await next();
    });   // doesn't work

How can I suppress the X-Powered-By header without introducing web.config files?

For every App Service, you will find a web.config file in the deployed files, you can check in the KUDU console.

Did you try it by removing this header from Program.cs  file. context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");

Refer this similar issue

One more option is to set the header to empty response.Headers.Add("X-Powered-By", string.Empty);

What are exactly those web sites? ASP.NET 4.x or ASP.NET Core? (as the latter doesn't generate X-Powered-By by default.) You also need to disclose how they were hosted on Azure App Service (Linux or Windows).

@LexLi They use ASP.NET Core, hosted under Windows and IIS

@Harshitha Agreed it has a web.config, which is generated if you don't provide one. Don't want to provide one to avoid maintenance overhead.

@Harshitha Tried Response.Headers.Remove, to no avail. Question updated.

As mentioned by @LexLi please add more details version of your App ? Deployed to Windows or Linux App Service ? How you have deployed ?

@Harshitha Tried your suggestion to set the header to empty string, to no avail. Updated question with this result

@Harshitha see my response to LexLi. They use ASP.NET Core, hosted under Windows and IIS. Deployed from Visual Studio, via Web Deploy

ASP.NET Core version ?

Couldn't reproduce this with .NET 8/IIS (try dotnet new mvc with a new project), as no such header is generated any more. You are supposed to be with .NET 8 and 9 now, as all older releases went end of life.

Refer this Doc once

Right now I am able to remove the header only from the Web.config file. Trying with app settings and middleware.

@user1147862 - Is your issue resolved?

Headers are added in later versions of .NET Core 8 and 9 only for the Apps deployed in Windows.

Use of Kestrel is limited only for the apps deployed in Linux App Service.

Linux App:

Also referred this Doc and tried to remove the header using the Middleware class.

Failed to remove the header, but it is allowing to add/ update the new one.


Thanks @Thomas Ardal for the explanation.

ASP.NET Core will return the X-Powered-By header. This happens when you host your website on IIS.  you simply cannot remove the header in middleware, since this is out of hands for ASP.NET Core. web.config to the rescue:

Output with Web.config:


By default Web.config file will be created in the application root directory.
The problem here is the setting which you updated from App Service will be removed once you re-deploy the app.

Also refer this blog for more details.
